# Why does Ubuntu create a guest group when guest account has been disabled?

Tags: permissions, login, security, lightdm

I'm using Ubuntu-Mate 16.04. 
I've disabled the guest account by creating a 50-no-guest.conf file in
the /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d folder, with the following command in the file:

```
[Seat:*]
allow-guest=false
```

That eliminated the guest login.

Before removing "Guest" I looked in "Manage Groups" and noticed that the guest creates a group entry. It looks something like:

```
guest-xxxxxx
```

After disallowing the guest account, I still show a guest entry in Group Manager. It is:

```
guest-7fan88
```

I can delete it, but it comes back next reboot. It is there even if I enable the guest account again.

Is this normal?

Do I have some other problem?

Can this be a security risk?

I'm very curious about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and used the command 
`sudo deluser --remove-all-files guest-xxxxxx` followed by `sudo deluser -group guest-xxxxxx`. It worked.

The man-page for the above is :
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/deluser.8.html